# Convert LINQ to DataTable Without Use CopyToDataTable

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Hello Every one I'm Tried To Use CopyToDataTable But Don't have my Visual Studio 2010 And 2015 this Method Please Help me How Convert Linq Query To DataTable With out Use CopyToDataTable Or Send me step by Step to Add This Method

Answer (score 1):

You can use `originalTable.Clone()` and a loop with `DataTable.ImportRow`:

```
DataTable tableResult = originalTable.Clone(); // empty
foreach(DataRow row in yourLinqQuery)
    tableResult.ImportRow(row);
```

This has also one advantage over [`CopyToDataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx): it doesn't cause an `InvalidOperationException` if the query doesn't return any rows. With this approach the table will be empty.